# Add custom class to the img of a agm-marker with Angular Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

i've got an Angular Google Map set up, with an agm-marker pulling in markers from a json.

Some of the data from this json needs the markers to be in a different direction such as up, down, left, right, as an arrow. This is passed through the JSON as well.

I have my agm-marker set up:

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let data of markerCollection;trackBy: eventId; let i = index" 
    [latitude]="data.item.coordinates[1]" [longitude]="data.item.coordinates[0]"
    [iconUrl]="data.item.url" [visible]="data.item.visible" (markerClick)="onMarkerClick(event)">
</agm-marker>
```

And thought that adding

```
[ngClass]="data.item.direction"
```

Would be able to add a class to the img tags, but it doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

after looking at ways to achieve this, i've realised there are only two ways, both less than ideal:

• Convert the image into a symbol, symbol properties have a "rotation" option available.

• Provide a different image per direction and code in the direction directly. In this case I appended the item.url with the direction that was passed into from the JSON feed and provided a different image accordingly.